# How display only files inside subdirs using the -haltr format?

Tags: linux, bash

How do I add the output looks of `ls -haltr` into the command below?

```
find 20180913/ -maxdepth 5 -not -type d -and -not -name '.*'
```

Basically I am trying to list only files inside my subdirs but need to display the file time stamp sorted by date with latest at the bottom.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `exec` option of `find`:

```
find 20180913/ -maxdepth 5 -not -type d -and -not -name '.*' -exec ls -haltr {}  +
```

Updated my answer based on PesaThe's correction.

Comment: thanks! i am a Windows guy and am impressed with the bash language!

Comment: This will not do any sorting though. Use `+` instead.

Comment: you are right, no sorting. Where do I add the plus sign please?

Comment: @Max `{} +` instead of `{} \;`.

Comment: Thank you. I supposed the reverse would be the negative sign - but it gave me an error.

Comment: @Max Nope, it must be `+`. To get the output reversed, just add or remove the `-r` option to `ls`.

Comment: If there are more results than will fit on a single command line (which is a big number, but not infinite), then `ls` will be run more than once. Since the sorting is happening within `ls`, this means the output could be multiple batches of results each independently sorted. `xargs --show-limits` is a handy way to find the maximum size of a command line.